# Пропорциональное увеличение контейнера C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Доброго времени суток!

Есть пикчербоксы, которым заданы начальные размеры, а также привязка к сторонам формы для резинового макета. Вопрос: как при расширении формы сохранить пропорцию сторон пикчербоксов?

Comment: Вы так очень долго будете ждать ответа, если вообще дождетесь. Добавьте код, в котором вы эти все контролы создаете, как делаете изменение размера, скриншотик в конце концов. А то при чтении вашего вопроса воображение не разыгралось, и идеи не появились. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если важны пропорции изображения, а не самого PictureBox, то можно просто установить:

```
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

после этого изображение всегда будет сохранять свои пропорции, независимо от пропорций PictureBox.

Можно также сделать привязку `PictureBox` только к одной из сторон формы, а размер по второй оси вычислять в событии `Resize`. Для примера, вычисление высоты для соотношения сторон `16:9` (ширина привязана к ширине формы):

```
private void pictureBox_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pictureBox.Height = (int)((float)pictureBox.Width / 16 * 9);
}
```

приведение к `float` здесь используется потому что иначе (если делить/умножать `int`) возникает заметная погрешность. Но такой вариант подойдёт не всегда.

Если описанные выше варианты не подошли, то наверное придётся обрабатывать `Resize` формы, определять размеры доступной области и по ним самостоятельно вычислять нужные размеры `PictureBox`. Например так (опять же для соотношения сторон `16:9`, входные параметры - максимальная доступная ширина и максимальная доступная высота):

```
Size AdjustSize(int max_width, int max_height)
{
    float width = max_width; // берём максимальную доступную ширину
    float height = (width / 16) * 9; // вычисляем по ней высоту
    if (height >= max_height) { // если полученная высота превышает доступную
        height = max_height; // пересчитываем заново
        width = (height / 9) * 16; // но теперь уже исходя из доступной высоты
    }
    return new Size((int)width, (int)height);
}
```